# When doing "uncompress gcc.tar.Z &" should the capital z be omitted?

Tags: tar

In the third edition of *"Learning the Bash shell"* by Newham and Rosenblatt the page 19 mentions uncompressing a file named `gcc.tar.Z`.

> Type `uncompress gcc.tar &` (you can omit the Z).

Why do the authors say "you can omit the Z"? Why not just keeping it?...

---

By `man uncompress` in Ubuntu 16.04 I reached to the Gunzip ("Gzip") manual that says:

> If  the  compressed  file  name is too long for its file system, gzip
>   truncates it.  Gzip attempts to truncate only the parts of the file
>   name longer than 3 characters.
>
> gunzip takes a list of files on its command line and replaces each
>   file whose name ends with .gz, -gz, .z, -z, or _z (ignoring case) and
>   which begins with the correct magic number with an uncompressed file
>   without the origi‐
>          nal extension.  gunzip also recognizes the special extensions .tgz and .taz as shorthands for .tar.gz and .tar.Z respectively.  When
>   compressing, gzip uses the .tgz extension if necessary instead of
>   truncating a file with  a
>          .tar extension.
>
> gunzip is sometimes able to detect a bad .Z

I admit it is not fully clear to me **why** the program has the aforementioned behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn’t say “should”, but you certainly *can*, because the `uncompress` utility’s `file` argument is [specified thus](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uncompress.html), as a convenience:

> A pathname of a file. If *file* already has the **.Z** suffix specified, it shall be used as the input file and the output file shall be named **file** with the **.Z** suffix removed. Otherwise, *file* shall be used as the name of the output file and **file** with the **.Z** suffix appended shall be used as the input file.

(I haven’t checked, but it’s likely this was the pre-existing behaviour, carried over to the spec.)

This is also supported by `gzip`, at least with its default `.gz` extension:

```
echo Hello > test
gzip test
ls -l test*
gunzip test
ls -l test*
cat test
```

Comment: Did you mean that the first `test` will have **.z**?

Comment: No, I meant that `gunzip` doesn’t require you to specify the extension.